# SwiftData: how to conform to @Attribute(.unique)

Tags: swift, swift-data

I’m testing SwiftData in a current project. I have an `Item` Model which conforms to `Identifiable` and `Codable`.
It has an `id` property of `Identifier<Item>`.
The `Identifier` looks as follows:

```swift
struct Identifier<Value>: Hashable, Codable {
    
    let value: UUID
    
    init() {
        self.value = UUID()
    }
    
    init(_ uuid: UUID) {
        self.value = uuid
    }
    
    static func fromString(_ string: String) -> Identifier<Value>? {
        guard let uuid = UUID(uuidString: string) else {
            return nil
        }
        return self.init(uuid)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I add `@Attribute(.unique)` to the `Item`s `id` property I get an crash running the app: "Property type is not valid for unique constraints."

So I looked up the conformity of `@Attribute` (CustomDebugStringConvertible, Decodable, Encodable, Equatable, Hashable) and added the protocols to the `Identifier` accordingly – but no luck with that.

```swift
struct Identifier<Value>: Hashable, Codable, Equatable, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    
    let value: UUID
    
    init() {
        self.value = UUID()
    }
    
    init(_ uuid: UUID) {
        self.value = uuid
    }
    var debugDescription: String {
        self.value.uuidString.debugDescription
    }
    
    static func fromString(_ string: String) -> Identifier<Value>? {
        guard let uuid = UUID(uuidString: string) else {
            return nil
        }
        return self.init(uuid)
    }
}
```

So how to achieve validity for the `@Attribute(.unique)` constraint? Or is this just an unfortunate bug in the beta?

There is a similar [question on the Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731509), but the workaround is not really satisfying.

It seems like `UUID` works, so I tried conforming my `Identifier` to the same protocols as `UUID` but had no luck with this either.

Comment: Most likely you get the error because Identifer is generic but it’s not clear why you made it generic.

Comment: But is there a workaround for that, other than just using `UUID`?

Comment: No I don’t think you can use generics here and why would you want to? Just create a property in your model with the type you want for the unique identifier, like UUID for instance.

Comment: Using generics for identifiers is just my taste. I find the code easier to read and maintain – for instance `[Identifier<Item>]` is much better to read than `[UUID]` imo. But since SwiftData is just a wrapper for CoreData, if I understand this correctly, it is may be reasonable that it rejects generics.

Comment: Nice approach, reminds me of https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-tagged, but I didn't manage make `@Attribute(.unique)` work even with a non-generic struct wrapping UUID 


@JoakimDanielson, you may find more reasoning behind use of generics for IDs at the link above 